# Delete a line in a txt file based on a set of strings in a loop

Tags: powershell

I have gone through this site and Stack Overflow trying to find a combination that will work. I am unsure if its the versions of PowerShell or what. But I cannot get this script to work like I want it to. I couldn't get the other scripts to work either. I would like the for the script to find a string in a file and delete that line without leaving a empty line. Currently this works but it leaves whatever text is not in the string and it will also leave the carriage return.

```
$Whitelist = @(
        String1
        String2
        String3 
)

$Path = .\whitelist.txt
$Content = Get-Content .\output.log
foreach ($Code in $whitelist)
        {
        $Content = $Content -replace $Code,""
        }
        $Content | Set-Content -Path .\output.log
```

I am unsure why the variables are not working. I keep getting errors that an argument is expected or path is not found.  I would like for it to look like this and understand my mistakes as I am trying to base my scripts off the same principles

```
$Whitelist = @(
        String1
        String2
        String3 
)

$Path = .\whitelist.txt
$Content = Get-Content -Path $Path
foreach ($Code in $whitelist)
        {
        $Content = $Content -replace $Code,""
        }
        $Content | Set-Content -Path $Path
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is the use of the `$Content` variable in the array. I mocked the below:

Source file contents:

> BaconToastSausageEggsKetchupBeans

Working code to remove Bacon, Eggs and Beans (sorry just had my breakfast):

```
$Whitelist = @(
    "Bacon"
    "Eggs"
    "Beans"
    )

ForEach ($Code in $Whitelist)
    {
        (Get-Content -Path C:\temp\data.txt).Replace($Code,'') | Set-Content C:\temp\data.txt
        Write-Host "Removing $Code" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
```

I added the Write-Host for confirmation that each string value was getting removed.

Updated source file:

> ToastSausageKetchup